# How to set url in docker-compose on which my wildfly container works?

Tags: networking, docker

How to set url in docker-compose on which my wildfly container works?

For example, now when I want to open web console:
    http://localhost:9990/console/App.html

What I want:
    http://myapp.local:9990/console/App.html

My docker compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  wildfly:
    image: wildfly-admin:dev
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 9990:9990
      - 8787:8787
    volumes:
      - logs:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/log/
    depends_on:
      - oracle_db
    environment:
      - JVM_OPTS=-Xmx4096m -Xms4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myapp.local` is the name as seen by your browser so doesn't depend on the container deployment, it depends on some DNS (or an entry in `/etc/hosts` or whatever that is on the browser's OS).

The external server name only matters in the container if you use HTTPS (certificate) or virtual hosts (Apache/Nginx config), and even this doesn't remove for name resolution in the browser.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if that works (check marks under the votes count).